# Where is the licence manager installed on ArcGIS Server 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

According to the ESRI Documentation, the licence manager for 10.3 aka. LSAdmin.exe is located here:

```
<installation_path>/arcgis/license10.3/LSAdmin
```

On my machine it is not there. I want to install and licence the image server extention but this is not going to happen if I can´t authorize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A license manager is only installed for concurrent use software seats, and only when the license manager application is explicitly installed on a host.  The Image Server Extension is a ArcGIS for Server extension, which is only available in single-seat keys.

Authorization is a multi-step process, which is [documented online](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/authorize-arcgis-server.htm), and can be summarized by:

1. License the software
2. Tell Esri what software you want to allocate
3. Esri generates an authorization
4. You apply the authorization to the instance

No concurrent-use license server software is involved in this process.

Comment: According to ESRI Docs..."A valid authorization file is required for ArcGIS for Server. To reconfigure your machine with an updated authorization file, run through the Software Authorization Wizard again. To launch the Software Authorization Wizard at a later time, click Start > Program Files > ArcGIS > Software Authorization." I have Windows Server 2012 and do not have a "start" button and therefore need to find the exe

Comment: I'm a Linux guy, where the "authorizeSoftware" utility is in tools.  Just search C:\ for "SoftwareAuthorization.exe".